# Несколько полей с одним foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте. Проблема в чем, у меня имеется таблица `ROOMS`:

```
id, slot_1, slot_2, slot_3, slot_4, slot_5
```

А так же есть таблица `USERS`:

```
uid, name
```

Как сделать такую штуку, чтоб каждый `slot_N` был связан с `USERS`?

Дело в том, что я это делаю внутри phpMyAdmin, там вообще связи не понимаю как устанавливать, но вроде как индексы сделал все, но как собственно при выборке прописывать `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Я сделал так, но это неправильно:
SELECT * FROM rooms
 LEFT JOIN users ON rooms.slot_1=users.id
 LEFT JOIN users ON rooms.slot_2=users.id
 LEFT JOIN users ON rooms.slot_3=users.id

Comment: У меня в slot_N цифренные айди, соответствующие тем, что uid из USERS. Выбрать хочу все содержимое USERS для каждого slot_N.

Comment: Для каждого slot_N, т.е. если в записи 5 _разных_ id пользователей, то вы хотите видеть в выборке 5 записей `rooms_id, ползователь такой-то` или одну запись с 5 именами, id и что там еще есть у пользователя ?   P.S. Вообще у вас база в очень странной форме, много колонок с id пользователей явно нарушают даже начальные нормальные формы. Может вам стоит подумать о другой структуре базы

Comment: а так: `SELECT * 
FROM rooms r 
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON r.slot_1 = u1.id 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON r.slot_2 = u2.id 
LEFT JOIN users u3 ON r.slot_3 = u3.id`

Comment: Согласен с @Mike должно быть что то такое: `room(id, slot); user(id, name); user_room(room_id, user_id` тогда и при изменении количества комнат нет необходимости изменять структура базы

Comment: В слотах всегда будут разные пользователи. Форму как нарушает, в USERS всего-лишь айди (уникальный, понятное дело). androschuk, попробую ваш запрос сейчас, суть понял с разными названиями.

Comment: Оо, точно. Как я забыл, это же можно через дополнительную таблицу делать. Спасибо, сейчас сделаю так.

Comment: Ну да, в таком случае у нас таблицы room и user выступают в виде справочников.

Comment: @Shevsky формально ваша таблица конечно не нарушала НФ. Но фактически для приложения был список значений для одного атрибута "слот", что нарушает 1НФ. И ведет просто к жуткого вида запросам :)

Comment: наличие/отсутвие foreign key никак не влияет на (не)возможность использования join в запросах. Он лишь гарантирует целостность связных данных, т.е. при указании foreign key вы обезапасиваете себя от возможности возникновения ситуации наличия связи с не существующим объектом.

Comment: Собственно, чтоб было понятно, я изобразил это: http://clip2net.com/clip/m393690/8ae8f-clip-33kb.png

Comment: Как мне теперь прописать SELECT?

Comment: @Vitalts понял, спасибо)

Comment: Все, я написал запрос. Спасибо всем :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  r.id AS id,
  s1.name AS slot_1,
  s2.name AS slot_2,
  s3.name AS slot_3,
  s4.name AS slot_4,
  s5.name AS slot_5
FROM
  rooms AS r
LEFT JOIN
  users AS s1
ON
  r.slot_1 = s1.ui‌​d
LEFT JOIN
  users AS s2
ON
  r.slot_2 = s2.ui‌​d
LEFT JOIN
  users AS s3
ON
  r.slot_3 = s3.ui‌​d
LEFT JOIN
  users AS s4
ON
  r.slot_4 = s4.ui‌​d
LEFT JOIN
  users AS s5
ON
  r.slot_5 = s5.ui‌​d;
```